check if variable has a certain value from external js file in Laravel Blade
Hi I'm brand new to Laravel and Blade (and kind of beginner to PHP) but not JS, so I've found how to do @if @else statements and I have an external .js file with a simple script that is returning a random number between 1 or 2 for now.
script.js


function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max + 1) - min) + min);
}

const randomHero = randomNumber(1, 2);

console.log(randomHero);



Then in the blade.php file I'm trying to check if the random number stored in the variable randomHero is either 1 or 2 with an if/else statement:
index.blade.php:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>
  <section id="main">
    @if(randomHero === 1)         
        @include('components.Hero1')   
    @else
        @include('components.Hero2')   
    @endif        
    </section>
</body>
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js')}}"></script>
</html>



However I keep getting the error Undefined variable randomHero so I'm guessing I'm either missing a step for passing the variable from the .js file into the blade file to use or I'm calling the varibale incorrectly?
Any help would be much appreciated thanks

@if() and @inlcude() are PHP syntax, but randomHero is a JS variable. PHP being a server-side language processes long before JS (a client side language) does, so no, you cannot check the value of a JS variable inside of PHP code; PHP is not aware of the value of any JS variable, since they don't exist when PHP executes. Move your randomNumber method to PHP (since it's literally just a random number) and you'd be able to check @if($randomHero === 1) ... @else ... @endif

Your
    @if(randomHero === 1)         
        @include('components.Hero1')   
    @else
        @include('components.Hero2')   
    @endif  

is being executed on the server while the page is being generated and then it's sent to the browser, i.e., the client-side, where your
const randomHero = randomNumber(1, 2);

is being executed much later. You will need to randomize, using the rand function of PHP, like
$randomHero = rand(0, 1);

Then you can pass this to your view:
public function render()
{
    return view('index', ['randomHero' => rand(0, 1)]);
}

and make sure that before the script that you defined you embed another script, like
<script>
    var randomHero = {{ randomHero }};
</script>


Thank you for all the explanations and code examples, as I said I'm a beginner and totally new to working with Laravel & PHP. So a lot of new concepts to me, and this helped my understanding and I have got it working now with your help :)

@Chobbit no worries, happy to help. All of us needed to start as beginners. Happy coding!

You can achieve this otherwise by calling the php rand function straight away from your blade file rather than defining js method to do this. It would be as shown below;
@if(rand(0,1) === 1)
   @include('components.Hero1') 
@else
   @include('components.Hero2')
@endif


Thank you for your help, I tested this and it worked great and very short hand which I like if it's available. I just didn't mark it as the answer as Lajos answer just has a bit more explanation on the answer and other ways to achieve the answer too. However this is great thank you
